# What does ArcGIS Server error (The required port '4000 ' is already in use) indicate?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, installation, map-service

I tried to publish my map in ArcGIS for Server 10.1, but when doing so the following error appeared:

The required port '4000 'is already in use.'

For your information I use ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1.

Comment: Have you read the online help about [**Ports used by ArcGIS Server**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000537000000) which includes information about **Ports 4000–4003**?

Comment: That should be an answer @PolyGeo

Answer (score 2):

Information about Ports 4000–4003 and Using a different set of port numbers can be found in the online help about [Ports used by ArcGIS Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000537000000).